# Как подсчитать количество новых (не прочитанных) личных сообщений?

Tags: логика, php, mysql

Есть такая таблица, как ее изменить чтоб можно было подсчитывать количество новых сообщений, для каждого пользователя:

```
user_id
admin_id
subject
text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Здравствуйте*

Для начала, Вам нужно добавить в вашу таблицу такой столбик как: `active`
Если данная строка будет равна **1** то сообщение *Не* прочитанное.

После чего, мы можем использовать данный код, *(Делать буду на сессиях)*:

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'  AND active='1'");

if(mysql_nuw_rows($sql) > 0){
  echo "У Вас новых сообщений: ".mysql_nuw_rows($sql);
}

?>
```

**Объяснения кода:**

1. Таблица `message` - Это Ваша таблица с сообщениями
2. `mysql_nuw_rows()` - Возвращает количество строк
3. Если **active=1** - Сообщение *не* прочитанное

Надеюсь, что я понятно изложил :)

Comment: После выдачи пользователю/ клика по метке "прочитано" - обнулять флаг "active" ajax'ом или обычным способом.

Comment: @istem, Да, Вы правы:)

Comment: Только вот ``active = 1`` - ужасно не говорящее название/значение. Лучше как-то обыграть слова read, shown или еще что-то вроде того. ИМХО, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему, у вас должно быть хотя бы две таблицы:

```
1) Таблица пользователей(и админов тоже): user_id, user_type и т.д.

2) Таблица сообщений: message_id, message_text, message_status, sender_id, reciever_id
```

Информацию о прочитанности сообщения хранить в message_status.

Вообще, есть такое понятие, как нормальные формы, так вот я помню его весьма смутно. *Возможно*, намного грамотнее было бы сделать 3 таблицы.

**UPD:** Количество новых сообщений:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message_table WHERE reciever_id = user_id AND message_status = 0
```

user_id - ID пользователя, сообщения которого мы подсчитываем

message_status = 0 , при условии, что 0 означает непрочитанное сообщение, а -1 прочитанное